# OOP - Function not defined?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying my hand at OOP, and it has not been kind to me recently. Here is my class:

```
class db {

protected $host = "";
protected $dbname = "";
protected $user = "";
protected $pass = "";

function execute($query, $parameters, $usefetch) {

    $dsn = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->dbname";
    $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$this->user,$this->pass);

    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    try {
        $statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($parameters);

        if($usefetch) {
            $result = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;
        } else { 
            return SUCCESS; 
        }
    }

catch(PDOException $ex) { return $ex; }

}

function __get($var) {
    return $this->$var;
}

}
```

When I try to define it and call the function "execute" I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function execute() in
>   /var/www/html/api/classes/sessions.php:49 Stack trace: #0
>   /var/www/html/index.php(3): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in
>   /var/www/html/api/classes/sessions.php on line 49

Here is how I am trying to call it (debugging)

```
$db = new db();
die(var_dump($db.execute("SELECT * FROM sessions", [], true)));
```

I don't see why this error is occuring. Could it be something with my php configuration? (it does not execute, even if I make dbexecute its own function and not an object)

Comment: Try `$db->` instead of `$db.`: `$db->execute(...yada,yada,yada`

Comment: -___________________________- there goes 3 hours of searching.

Comment: Time well wasted! :D

Comment: @Rasclatt in another class I am trying to call $db->execute() but it is saying it is saying $db is undefined. I am declaring $db = new db(); in the global scope.

Comment: You will have to show that part. Hard to tell without seeing it. If it's totally unrelated, you probably should mark as solved then pose that as a new question.

Comment: The relevant part: http://paste.ee/p/PMG6J

Comment: That one is because you have it out of scope. You need to inject that connection into your other class.

Comment: But it is in the global scope?

Comment: Are you more familiar with Javascript than php?

Comment: I am more familiar with oop js than php, yes. It works when I create the $deb object inside the construct, but is there a way I can avoid that?

Comment: Yeah, in Javascript that is considered in the global scope, but in PHP it's not. You have to inject that object into the `__construct()` (or whichever method you want to use it in) or you can create a singleton (static) method (so you use the same resource all the time) and instantiate it inside the class (not a popular way to do it).

Comment: So you would do like `class Session { public function __construct(db $db,$token) {...etc` then you would do `$session = new Session(new db,$token);`

Comment: If you need to move that `db` object throughout the methods in the class, then you assign it to a variable inside the `__construct()` so `$this->db = $db;` then you could use that in all other methods inside the class.

Comment: So the final session class would be like: `class Session { private $db; public function __construct(db $db,$token) { $this->db = $db; ..etc..`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a concatenation `.` where you should have `->`. Should be:

```
$db->execute("SELECT * FROM sessions", [], true)
```

Instead of:

```
// This is a typo concatenation OR you may be temporarily confused ;) with
// a Javascript object which does use the period for object/method
$db.execute("SELECT * FROM sessions", [], true))
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that `var_dump()` is attemping to concatenate the string `$db` with the output of the `execute()` function in global scope.